# PHP 8.0, SQLite3, TypeError

Tags: php, sql

**Ошибка:**

```
Provider\SQLite3Provider::getPosition(): Return value must be of type pocketmine\world\Position, string returned
```

**Код:**

```
public static function getPosition(string $username) : Position
{
    $username = strtolower($username);
    return AP::getInstance()->getBaseObject(false)->query("SELECT * FROM usersDataOffline WHERE username = '$username'")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)['position'];
}
```

**В Базу Данных вписываю это:**

```
$baseObject = AP::getInstance()->getBaseObject(false)->prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO usersDataOffline (username, position, yaw, pitch) VALUES (:username, :position, :yaw, :pitch)");
$baseObject->bindValue(":username", strtolower($username));
$baseObject->bindValue(":position", $player->getPosition());
$baseObject->bindValue(":yaw", $player->getLocation()->getYaw());
$baseObject->bindValue(":pitch", $player->getLocation()->getPitch());
$baseObject->execute();
```

Comment: Что вам не ясно из текста ошибки? Вам чётко пишут что не так.

Comment: я хочу получить Position, но мне выдает string,  хотя я вписываю в БД Position

Comment: Какой тип возвращается из метода $player->getPosition()?

Comment: Ну Position выдает